# Find values (integers) in string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How would I find the width and height pixels in a string like this:

```
mytext = "480 x 800 pixels, 4.0 inches (~233 ppi pixel density)"
```

I have tried this:

```
mytext[/(\d+)\sx\s(\d+)\spixels/]
```

But is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
width, height = mytext.match(/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*pixels/).captures

width  # 480
height # 800
```

**Explanation**

[String#match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-match) will return a [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/MatchData.html) object. If we convert it to an array, we can see what's going on a little nicer

```
mytext.match(/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*pixels/i).to_a
# => ["480 x 800 pixels", "480", "800"]

mytext.match(/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*pixels/i).captures
# => ["480", "800"]
```

**Notes**

- We really only care about `MatchData[1]`, and `MatchData[2]`, conveniently, [MatchData#captures](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) includes all captured matches without `MatchData[0]`
- I used `\s*` so that there could be optional spaces. Other values that would match include:

  - `480x800 pixels`
  - `480 x800pixels`
  - `480  x  800 pixels`
- I also add the `i` modifier to the regexp to make it case insensitive. This supports values like:

  - `480 x 800 Pixles`
  - `480 X 800 PIXELS`

---

**Original post**

This might help you

```
width, height = mytext.scan /\d+/

puts width  # 400
puts height # 800
```

---

**Explanation**

`String#scan` will scan a string for a pattern and return an array of all matches

```
scan = mytext.scan /\d+/
#=> ["480", "800", "4", "0", "233"]
```

So then we just grab the first two vars

```
width, height = scan
```

This is just a shortcut for

```
width = scan[0]
height = scan[1]
```

Either way,

```
width  # 480
height # 800
```

Comment: thanks naomik. I would actually like to make sure that it follows this pattern too. \d+x\d+, because in some strings I will have the order reversed as ``4.0 inches 480 x 800 pixels``

Comment: @HommerSmith, I made a couple additional edits. I hope they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You used `myext` in the second statement instead of `myext`. This may cause the regex to fail.

Comment: I believe this should have been a comment pointing out the typo, not an answer.

Comment: I posted it as an answer because it may have been the cause of the regex working incorrectly. Otherwise, if it was more trivial, I would agree entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted the numbers, I'd do:

```
values = /(\d+)\sx\s(\d+)\spixels/.match(mytext)
width=values[1]
height=values[2]
```